# Maven testResources not being applied in a multi module/profile project

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, intellij-13

I have a Maven multi module/profile project whose test resources are apparently not being applied when running the test module. These resources define which data base the aplication will work (one is my create.sql script file):

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "${db.name}";
CREATE DATABASE "${db.name}"
  WITH TEMPLATE = template0
   OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

The 'project' structure is:

```
project/ pom.xml //packing: pom
|
+-- core/ pom.xml //packing: war
|
+-- module-a/ pom.xml //packing: jar
|
+-- module-b/ pom.xml //packing: jar
|
+-- test/ pom.xml //packing: jar
        +-- ** src/test/resources/create.sql **
```

The root 'project' pom is defined as:

```
<?xml ... maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<!-- ... -->
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <!-- global properties -->
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>module-a</module>
    <module>module-b</module>
    <module>test</module> <!-- CAN BE REMOVED -->
</modules>

<repositories>
    <!-- some repo declarations -->
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- all general dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The 'core' definition is the war application itself:

```
<?xml ... maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <!-- 'project' is the parent -->
</parent>

<!-- ... -->
<packaging>war</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev-a</id>
        <properties>
            <profileName>dev-a</profileName>
            **<db.name>db</db.name>**
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev-b</id>
        <properties>
            <profileName>dev-b</profileName>
            **<db.name>db</db.name>**
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test-a</id>
        <properties>
            <profileName>test-a</profileName>
            **<db.name>db_test</db.name>**
            <selenium.context>http://127.0.0.1:9999/${profileName}</selenium.context>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test-b</id>
        <properties>
            <profileName>test-b</profileName>
            **<db.name>db_test</db.name>**
            <selenium.context>http://127.0.0.1:9999/${profileName}</selenium.context>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <finalName>${profileName}##${app.version}.${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <useCache>false</useCache>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${project.artifactId}#${maven.build.timestamp}</Implementation-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

The module definitions are quite simple and similar (module-b is supressed):

```
<?xml ... maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <!-- 'project' is the parent -->
</parent>

<artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And finally my test module, a jar module that encapsultes some cucumber tests and sql script files:

```
<?xml  ... maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <!-- 'project' is the parent -->
</parent>

<!-- ... -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- All test dependencies + ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>surefire-it</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>Tomcat 7</server>
                <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <port>9999</port>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-selenium</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="true">
                                <arg value="/u/c" />
                                <arg value="${basedir}/src/test/resources/start-selenium.bat" />
                                <arg line="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib/selenium-server-standalone-${selenium.version}.jar" />
                                <arg line="-timeout 30 -port 4444" />
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With this structure when I run dev-a or dev-b I got two different war files with all properties correctly replaced, **but when I execute test-a or test-b the resources inside my test module are not affected by the properties inside test profiles, the ${db.name} remains intact**

So I have tried another approach **moving the test profiles from core to test module and the replacements are done for the test module with the right database name (db_test) but as a downside the core war module don't (remains with db)**.

It's relatively ease to notice that my structure is wrong, but the gist is: **what modification is necessary to have the war and test-jar files using the same key property for the right profile (dev|test)?** How should I redeclare the modules and their hierarchy? Aforesaid, I'm trying to achieve:

```
runnig dev-a: A war file using db + module-a.jar
runnig dev-b: A war file using db + module-b.jar
runnig test-a: A war file using db_test + module-a.jar + test-jar using the same database db_test
runnig test-b: A war file using db_test + module-b.jar + test-jar using the same database db_test
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved a partial solution between what I think it would be the ideal approach (WITH test module) and the pratical solution (maven tasks generating build or executing integrated tests).

**So I moved the test classes and resources from test module to the war module and removed the module test in the parent pom.**